# Unstable ping to router on MacBook Pro 2018

Tags: macbook-pro, network, wifi

I recently bought a MacBook Pro 2018, and I am experiencing an unstable connection. I mainly notice it when I am trying to play games, as spikes in latency is less notable within a browser, for instance. So the problem seems to be that the latency to my router spikes once every second or so. Here is an example of pinging my router every 200ms.

```
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=35 ttl=64 time=101.689 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=36 ttl=64 time=2.839 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=37 ttl=64 time=83.216 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=38 ttl=64 time=2.965 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=39 ttl=64 time=3.788 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=40 ttl=64 time=137.253 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=41 ttl=64 time=2.679 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=42 ttl=64 time=2.925 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=43 ttl=64 time=17.099 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=44 ttl=64 time=3.308 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=45 ttl=64 time=163.689 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=46 ttl=64 time=3.797 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=47 ttl=64 time=3.681 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=48 ttl=64 time=3.319 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=49 ttl=64 time=22.506 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=50 ttl=64 time=190.864 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=51 ttl=64 time=4.533 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=52 ttl=64 time=3.480 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=53 ttl=64 time=3.927 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=54 ttl=64 time=3.422 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=55 ttl=64 time=221.810 ms
```

As you can see, the pings are all over the place, and this behavior is consistent. On the contrary, if I perform the same test on my MacBook Pro 2011 on the same network, all pings are ~2.5ms consistently, so this Mac doesn't have this issue at all. I am using WiFi, but I am literally next to the router, so the connection is strong. And like I said, the issue doesn't appear on other devices, so I don't think the router/network is to blame. I looked at other wireless networks around, and there are not that many, so network congestion (or whatever it's called) shouldn't be the issue; also because it works on other devices. I have also performed the same test on a different network at another physical location, and the results are the same.

I have tried turning off "Wake for Wi-Fi network access" in the Energy Saver preferences, but that didn't make any difference.

I should mention that this happens even when I close all applications I have running, and I see nothing suspicious within the Activity Monitor.

Any ideas what could be causing this, or ideas as to what I should do from here to further debug the issue? Thanks!